# Number of rules for symmetric group Sn

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

The permutation group $S_n$ can be constructed using different number of generators. Generally, one can generate $S_n$ by using the set $\{(12),(13),...(1n)\}$ or the set $\{(12),(12...n)\}$, which clearly have different cardinality.

My question is, is the number of rules that they satisfy the same regardless of the number of generators one uses?

Comment: You need to say exactly what you mean by "the number of rules that they satisfy".

Comment: Suggestion : Let $S$ be the set of generators.  The " number of rules that they satisfy" is the smallest cardinal of a set $R$ of relations among those generators such that $G$ has presentation $< S \,|\, R>$.

Comment: @olivierroche well that will certainly depend on the choice of generators.

Comment: A key concept here is that of *deficiency*, both of the group and of the presentation. In short, the deficiency of a *presentation* $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ is $|X|-|R|$, whereas the deficiency of a *group* is the minimum deficiency of all the presentations of that group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Read "the number of rules that $S$ satisfy", sorry.

Comment: The answer is yes for $\mathcal{S}_3$ :

Comment: @OlivierRoche You seem to understand the question, but I do not, and I find it hard to think of any interpretation for which the answer would be yes for $S_3$ in particular. There are two generator, two relation presentations of $S_3$, but if you use more than two generators then you will need more relations.

Comment: @DerekHolt One could eg assume that the set $S$ of generators is minimal for inclusion. One could then think of $S$ as a "basis". Of course, there is no analog to the exchange principle that one has in linear algebra.

In my opinion, the answer will still be no, but I'm too lazy to compute an actual counter-example.

Comment: Actually a counterexample would be assuming that the five non-identity elements of $S_3$ are generators. But them one has to specify the rules associated to their orders. These become *at least* five rules, which are already more than the three rules needed for the case when we use a transposition and s 3-cycle as the only two generators.

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona Can you write/give a link to these 3 rules please?

Comment: x^3=y^2=1, yx=x^ y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the naive statement is NO.

Take the set of generators $S = \{\sigma_i | 1\leqslant i < n\}$, where $\sigma_i$ is the transposition $(i\, (i+1))$. Consider the following set of relations :

$$R := \{\sigma _{i}^{2}=1 |1\leqslant i<n\} \cup \{\sigma _{i}\sigma _{j}=\sigma _{j}\sigma _{i} |j\neq i\pm 1\} \cup \{(\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1})^3=1 | 1\leqslant i < n\}$$
Then $\mathcal{S}_n = < S \,|\, R>$.
Now take $x := \sigma_1 \sigma_3$. If your set of generators is $S' := S \cup \{x\}$, you'll need to have an extra relation where $x$ occurs, eg $x = \sigma_1 \sigma_3$.